# How to create a data.frame from a vector with multiple strings in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, input

I have an output from another program that I want to analyze in R. However, the output is too difficult to analyze due to the way it was written and I want to transform it in a data.frame. I explain it below.

I have many vectors with the following pattern:

```
[["tree:" 3 "bromeliad:" 326 "local:" "canopy" 698 221 "height:" 5 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 208 208 267 267 268 268 233 233] ["tree:" 3 "bromeliad:" 538 "local:" "canopy" 748 187 "height:" 8 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 214 214 267 267 268 268 233 233] ["tree:" 3 "bromeliad:" 481 "local:" "canopy" 670 194 "height:" 8 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 208 208 267 267 268 268 233 233] ["tree:" 4 "bromeliad:" 412 "local:" "canopy" 701 206 "height:" 6 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 208 208 267 267 268 268 233 233] ["tree:" 4 "bromeliad:" 843 "local:" "canopy" 742 197 "height:" 6 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 208 214 267 267 268 268 233 233] ["tree:" 5 "bromeliad:" 473 "local:" "canopy" 714 169 "height:" 7 "origin:" "seed" "ancestry:" [34] "alleles:" 167 167 169 169 208 208 267 267 268 268 233 233]]
```

Explaining the above output: 
It has a "[" delimiting the whole data, and another "[" delimiting each row.
The name of each column is between "" and have a ":". It repeats every line. 
We have character and numeric variables.
The last 12 variables referred to a genotype, where we have the two alleles of 6 microsatellites (so, they can be merged in the same cell or be split).

From this example, I sought to have a data.frame as the following example:

```
tree    bromeliad   local   x   y   height  origin  ancestry    locus.1 locus.2 locus.3 locus.4 locus.5 locus.6
3   326 canopy  698 221 5   seed    34  167167  169169  208208  267267  268268  233233
3   538 canopy  748 187 8   seed    34  167167  169169  214214  267267  268268  233233
3   481 canopy  670 194 8   seed    34  167167  169169  208208  267267  268268  233233
4   412 canopy  701 206 6   seed    34  167167  169169  208208  267267  268268  233233
4   843 canopy  742 197 6   seed    34  167167  169169  208208  267267  268268  233233
5   473 canopy  714 169 7   seed    34  167167  169169  208208  267267  268268  233233
```

I think someone that understands more about programming language can deal better than me with this challenge. Can you help me? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do in Melissa way, but I don't know why it doesn't work.
However, based on it, I changed my code as follow and it works:

```
pop_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(genots_list)){
  input <- genots_list[[i]]
  input2 <- str_split(input, "\\] \\[")
  input3 <- unlist(input2, recursive = F)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0,ncol = 14))
  for (j in 1:length(input3)){
    input4 <- unlist(strsplit(noquote(input3[[j]])," "))
    df <- rbind(df,data.frame(
      tree = as.integer(input4[2]),
      bromeliad = as.integer(input4[4]),
      local = noquote(input4[6]),
      x = as.integer(input4[7]),
      y = as.integer(input4[8]),
      height = as.integer(input4[10]),
      origin = noquote(input4[12]),
      ancestry = gsub("\\[|\\]", "", input4[14]),
      locus_1 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[16]),as.integer(input4[17]),sep="")),
      locus_2 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[18]),as.integer(input4[19]),sep="")),
      locus_3 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[20]),as.integer(input4[21]),sep="")),
      locus_4 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[22]),as.integer(input4[23]),sep="")),
      locus_5 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[24]),as.integer(input4[25]),sep="")),
      locus_6 = as.integer(paste(as.integer(input4[26]),as.integer(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", input4[27])),sep=""))
      )
    )
  }
  pop_list[[i]] <- df
}
```

Where i is the list member I gave in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want.  The genotype is stored as a vector inside a list-column.  Admittedly, this isn't very robust - it will fail if the columns aren't exactly as described - and in that order, or if there are any symbols inside the contents (including decimals.  If you have decimals, I'll need to fiddle a bit with the regex portion).

```
output <- str_split(input, "\\] \\[") %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>%
  str_match_all( "\\w+") %>%
  map_dfr(.f = function(vec) {
    data_frame(
      tree = vec[2] %>% as.integer(),
      bromeliad = vec[4] %>% as.integer(),
      local = vec[6],
      x = vec[7] %>% as.integer(),
      y = vec[8] %>% as.integer(),
      height = vec[10] %>% as.integer(),
      origin = vec[12],
      ancestery = vec[14] %>% as.integer(),
      locus = list(locus=vec[16:27] %>% as.integer())
    )
  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Melissa! I'm not in my PC now. But I'll try as soon as possible!